# Error in jenkins pipeline for dependency library not compiling

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are getting this error in Jenkins, but in locally...

ERROR in node_modules/i18next-xhr-backend/index.d.ts:70:3 - error TS2416: Property 'readMulti' in type 'I18NextXhrBackend' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BackendModule'.

Any inputs on my it might be breaking. Basically it's not compiling...

Comment: Could you please specify your Spartacus version, Angular version, Node and npm version (from Jenkins)

Comment: We were able to get past this issue, with having included package-lock file.

We found that there were major release differences if we don't include lock file and that was causing errors.